# "I want my photograph taken" or "I want to have my photograph taken"?

Tags: ambiguity

I am reading the story *With the photographer* written by Stephen Leacock (he was native speaker). The story is given online [here](https://www.snappynotes.net/post/with-the-photographer-summary).

In the beginning, he says

> I want my photograph taken.

Shouldn't this sentence like following?

> I want to have my photograph taken.

Because he went to studio to have his photograph taken. Doesn't first sentence mean his photograph is already taken and he is there just to collect it. If yes, why first sentence is used here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means exactly what he wants it to mean.

*Want* can be followed by a participial clause, usually a passive (past) participle:

Examples:

> I want a house built.

> I want that floor scrubbed.

> I want them banned from here.

While *I want to have my photograph taken* is perfectly good as well, there is no ambiguity in Leacock's sentence: it cannot mean what you suggest, because what he wants is not "the photograph" but "the photograph to be taken".

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now I got it. I didn't know this type of sentence construction. I read it first time. Then can I say *I don't like my photo (to be) taken* when I meant *I don't like to be photographed* (means I don't like when someone captures my photo.)?

Comment: I think it's marginal with _like_: I wouldn't say _I don't like my photograph taken_,  but I think some people might. I would say _I don't like having my photograph taken_. On the other hand, it's normal with _would like_, which is effectively the same as _want_, but a bit politer: _I would like my photograph taken_.

Answer (score 0):

"I want my photograph taken" = "I want my photograph **to be** taken [by someone]"

"I want to have my photograph taken." This is the [causative form](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/causative) of the verb = "I want to **arrange for** my photograph **to be** taken [by someone]."

Compare
I want my hair cut.

and

I want to have my hair cut.